# Creating a Java Applet exception: missing <jnlp> field

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start, next-generation-plugin

I'm kinda at my wit's end trying to get my Java game to work in a browser. I've successfully managed to get it to run as a Java Web Start application but converting it to an in-browser-window applet is driving me crazy.

MYAPPLET.jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp href="MYAPPLET.jar" codebase="http://www.myDomain.com/directoryContainingJar/">
    <information>
        <title>Name</title>
        <vendor>----</vendor>
        <offline-allowed />
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.4+"
             href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="MYAPPLET.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
        name="Name"
        main-class="main.MainClass"
        width="700"
        height="600">
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

In my html file:

```
<applet width="700" height="600" code="main.MainClass">
     <param name="jnlp_href" value="MYAPPLET.jnlp">
</applet>
```

I get this error when loading the page:

```
ExitException[ 3]MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.redirectLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: ExitException[ 3]MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>], bail out
```

I have changed the main class so that it `extends JApplet` instead of `JFrame` but apart from that I don't know what to do.

And yes, I have read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html and Google'd the error.

Comment: Note that the `documentBase` is a required attribute of the [`applet-desc` element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#applet_desc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNLP element should be:

```
<jnlp href="MYAPPLET.jnlp" codebase="http://www.myDomain.com/directoryContainingJar/">
```

or, since it would be more common to have the codebase 1st..

```
<jnlp codebase="http://www.myDomain.com/directoryContainingJar/" href="MYAPPLET.jnlp">
```

But make sure you validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It can check a JNLP far better than I can by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in JDK version 1.6 update 14: http://www.canoo.com/jira/browse/UBA-8105. What JDK are you using? Try with a JDK 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have stumbled into another error though (I updated the question). It complains about a missing <jnlp> field even though it can be seen in my jnlp file :(

Comment: Well I was using 1.6 update 29 but I'm currently installing 1.7 just to make sure it's not that bug.